# my update of the prototype "string" cannot be printed to with log

Tags: javascript

I dont get how I can remove a list of words from a string using this type of formalism: 
`string.my_function(parameter[])`

```
text_val = "je vous appel concernant le truc rouge"

String.prototype.clean_string = function (stop_words) {
    for (i = 0; i < stop_words.length; i++)
    {
        this.split(stop_words[i]).join('');
    }
};

console.log(text_val.clean_string(['concernant','le']));
```

I have un undefined as a result and I don't get why.

I expect the result:

```
"je vous appel truc rouge"
```

Comment: strings are immutable. `this` is immutable too. Copy `this` into a local variable, e.g. `str`, then mutate that with `str = str....` and finally `return str`.

Comment: Thanks ! It's basic but i didn't knew it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use filter to strip the stop_words and then join the result:

```js
text_val = "je vous appel concernant le truc rouge";

String.prototype.clean_string = function (stop_words) {
    let splitted = this.split(' ');

    for (i = 0; i < stop_words.length; i++) {
        splitted = splitted.filter(w => w != stop_words[i]);
    }
    return splitted.join(' ');
};

console.log(text_val.clean_string(['concernant','le']));
```